# Openvpn site-to-site: cannot access remote network, remote network can access local

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, openvpn, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn

I have poured over so many suggestions and spent so many hours (upon hours) on this and simply cannot come up with why a specific vpn connection is only one-sided.
I have a centos aws ec2 server (remote network) and a pfsense in a local network. I have set up both a client-server and server-client model but for some reason only the remote network can connect to the local network. The local network can ping the remote network's vpn server but nothing else within the subnet.

I created a separate local network at a separate physical location and different ISP to the exact same server in aws, using the exact same settings (save for the subnet) and everything just works as expected.

One would assume it's the subnet settings, but I have triple checked the subnet and static routes as well tried /24 subnet out of desperation.

What else should I look for at this point?

Comment: Routes, of course, and firewalls.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes but the routes are nearly identical save for the different scopes, as well the firewall rules are the same and also to the same server (no rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tunneling traffic from the problematic side was coming in as the tunnel ip when viewed in tcpdump on the ec2. Turns out the pfsense had Hybrid Outbound rule generation turned on in NAT and not the default Automatic Outbound.